# Find a decomposition of K2n into two subgraphs G1 and G2 such that χ(G1) + χ(G2) = n+2.

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

I've found a decomposition for $K_4$ into 2 $P_2$'s and a $C_4$ and several decompositions of $K_6$ and above that fit this property where $\chi(G)$ is the chromatic number of the given graph. How would this generalize to $K_{2n}$ for $n \geq 2, n \in \mathbb{N}$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the subgraphs don't need to be connected you can decompose $K_{2n}$ into $2K_n$ and $K_{n,n}$ with chromatic numbers $n$ and $2$ respectively. If they do need to be connected, remove one edge from the second subgraph and add it to the first.

Answer (score 1):

Label the vertices $u_1,v_1,\ldots,u_n,v_n$.  Let one subgraph be the cycle $u_1v_1\cdots u_nv_nu_1$ with chromatic number $2$.  The other subgraph $G_2$ consists of all other edges.

Now $G_2$ contains all edges $u_ju_k$ and hence has chromatic number at least $n$.  Also  there is an $n$-colouring where $u_j$ and $v_j$ have colour $j$ (because $u_j$ and $v_j$ are not adjacent in $G_2$).  So $G_2$ has chromatic number exactly $n$.

Comment: I assume you mean to clarify that you separate the second half of your decomposition into groupings of $K_m$ for $m \leq n$ to avoid having too great a chromatic number. For example, Consider $K_6$ where you have a $C_6$ in your decomposition and then another decomposition which would contain $K_4$ if all the vertices and/or edges were lumped together. While your answer works, I think taking these extra edges in $G_2$ and adding them to the cycle $C_n$ to make a complete bipartite graph $K_{n,n}$ is a bit more elegant. Interesting solution though.

Comment: To me this is the obvious way to do it - take out a cycle which has chromatic number $2$.  Then the rest needs to have chromatic number $n$, and this is what I have proved, unless I have made a mistake.

Comment: Your decomposition works as well. I just like the other approach to get a graph with chromatic number 2 via the bipartite graph as opposed to the cycle.